# Align menu right if li nth-child is 1 or 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mega menu  which shows dropdown either of left or right side so far i am not able to calculate offset.left properly and it behaves different different resolutions.

So i thought of show First and Second dropdown menu on right side and rest on left, But i am not sure how to make nth-child element work on if statement.

Simple Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/42MfQ/1/

My mega menu sample which is close  show show up as   this [image]
Actual Fiddle Sample of mega menu http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/13/

I would appreciate help to make this script show menu's properly.

Right now this code is not working properly

```
if (($(this).offset().left) + 200 > $('.menu-wrapper').width()) {
    $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last");
}
```

For this reason i though of show first,second dropdown menu on right side and rest of left side which will avoid auto detection as calculated by above code.

I am not sure how to write this code

```
   if($( "li:nth-child(1)" ) == true || "li:nth-child(2)" == true ))
   {
     alert('show dd menu on right side of parent menu');  
   }
```

else
{
 alert('show dd menu on left side of parent menu');
}

Comment: Not all the menus actually drop down something. Is that by design? Also I'm not sure what the Javascript is supposed to achieve. The answer to the question seems to be simply "use `:nth-child(-n+2)`" but I don't know if that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I simply decide to use following jquery to make it work with any unexpected result.

This simple add a  `dropdown-last` class which align submenu on left side of text. Below is an example & one can use it to make it work in a way one wants

```
$("#menu").on("mouseenter", ":nth-child(4)", function () { $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last"); });
$("#menu").on("mouseenter", ":nth-child(5)", function () { $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last"); });
$("#menu").on("mouseenter", ":nth-child(6)", function () { $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last"); });
```

As following jQuery was giving me unexpected results on different screens resolution.

```
    if (($(this).offset().left) + 200 > $('.menu-wrapper').width()) {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last");
    }
```